# How to Pivot the data in the javascript from given JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, pivot

How can I pivot the data from the given JSON array of objects by taking three variables as index columns(grouping columns), one variable as column and one variable as value.

Input Data is as follows :

```
const data = [
  {
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "John Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "1234567890",
    tenantemail: "johndoe@example.com",
    date: "JAN 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
{
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "JAN 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
 {
    unitname: "A103",
    tenantname: "Mark Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987454321",
    tenantemail: "marksmith@example.com",
    date: "JAN 2022",
    paidamount: 1500,
  }
  {
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "John Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "1234567890",
    tenantemail: "johndoe@example.com",
    date: "FEB 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
  
  {
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "FEB 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
{
    unitname: "A103",
    tenantname: "Mark Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987454321",
    tenantemail: "marksmith@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1500,
  }
{
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "John Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "1234567890",
    tenantemail: "johndoe@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
{
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
 {
    unitname: "A103",
    tenantname: "Mark Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987454321",
    tenantemail: "marksmith@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1500,
  }
{
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "Mark Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "093214567",
    tenantemail: "markdoe@example.com",
    date: "APR 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
{
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "APR 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
];
```

This is very simple to be achieved in Python by using Pandas, but unable to figure out how can we achieve in javascript.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Desired output :

```
const data = [
{
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "John Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "1234567890",
    tenantemail: "johndoe@example.com",
    "JAN 2022" : 1000,
    "FEB 2022" : 1000,
    "MAR 2022" : 1000
},
{
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    "JAN 2022" : 1200,
    "FEB 2022" : 1200,
    "MAR 2022" : 1200,
    "APR 2022" : 1200
},
{
    unitname: "A103",
    tenantname: "Mark Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987454321",
    tenantemail: "marksmith@example.com",
    "JAN 2022" : 1500,
    "FEB 2022" : 1500,
    "MAR 2022" : 1500
  
},
{
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "Mark Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "093214567",
    tenantemail: "markdoe@example.com",
    "APR 2022" : 1000
}
]
```

Comment: I would suggest using the reduce function, using the unitname as an object key, and then using Object.values to transform the object into an array =)

Comment: There's two 'MAR 2022' and no 'FEB 2022' in the input data for Mark Smith, which doesn't tally with the expected data (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could make use of `reduce` grouping by the unitnumber

```js
const data = [
  {
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "John Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "1234567890",
    tenantemail: "johndoe@example.com",
    date: "JAN 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
{
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "JAN 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
 {
    unitname: "A103",
    tenantname: "Mark Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987454321",
    tenantemail: "marksmith@example.com",
    date: "JAN 2022",
    paidamount: 1500,
  },
  {
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "John Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "1234567890",
    tenantemail: "johndoe@example.com",
    date: "FEB 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
  
  {
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "FEB 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
{
    unitname: "A103",
    tenantname: "Mark Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987454321",
    tenantemail: "marksmith@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1500,
  },
{
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "John Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "1234567890",
    tenantemail: "johndoe@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
{
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
 {
    unitname: "A103",
    tenantname: "Mark Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987454321",
    tenantemail: "marksmith@example.com",
    date: "MAR 2022",
    paidamount: 1500,
  },
{
    unitname: "A101",
    tenantname: "Mark Doe",
    tenantphonenumber: "093214567",
    tenantemail: "markdoe@example.com",
    date: "APR 2022",
    paidamount: 1000,
  },
{
    unitname: "A102",
    tenantname: "Jane Smith",
    tenantphonenumber: "0987654321",
    tenantemail: "janesmith@example.com",
    date: "APR 2022",
    paidamount: 1200,
  },
];


let w = data.reduce((x, y)=> {
  y[y.date] = y.paidamount;
  delete y['date'];
  delete y['paidamount'];
  let key = y.unitname.concat(y.tenantemail); 
  if(!key in x) x[key] = y;
  else x[key] = {...x[key], ...y};
  return x;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(w));
```

Comment: @BenStephens thanks. edited it accordingly